# C++: Convert vector<char> to a UTF-8 string so that I can send over a Websocket

Tags: c++, utf-8, websocket

As the title suggests, I have a raw vector of chars, and I need to encode this as a proper UTF-8 string so that I can send the result over a Websocket. My inclination was simply to do this

```
    std::vector<char> data;

    // Fill data ..., then 

    std::string utfData(data.begin(), data.end());

    // Finally, send utfData
```

However, on the browser side, it is telling me that my data is not a properly encoded UTF-8 string. What is wrong with my logic here and how should I be converting this `vector<char>` to a UTF8 string?

If the logic above seems correct, then I will have to investigate the other code, but I doubt the the problem lies there since I have used the c++ server and javascript client to send normal std::string objects before without a problem. However, on the receiving side, it won't even receive the message now because it says that it is not proper UTF-8 string. That is, at the WebSocket protocol level, it is rejecting the message that my server is publishing.

Comment: This is likely meaningless. A vector of `char` is already encoded according to *some* encoding. Could be UTF-8 to begin with.

Comment: Convert to UTF-8, from what?

Comment: This is just raw data. There is no encoding. But can't we just pretend that the encoding is ANSI extended?

Comment: You need to know the initial encoding in order to convert to utf-8.

Comment: Each element from the vector is a char. Assume any extended ANSI encoding you wish.

Comment: @bremen_matt If those chars have the highest order bit set that means it is not ASCII but rather some encoding. You need to know what that encoding is in order to be able to convert that to utf-8. Normally, on Linux, everything uses utf-8 though.

Comment: You can assume whatever you want but if some of those chars fall out of the `UTF-8` range then they are not going to produce legal `UTF-8` by simple copying. Without knowing what `UTF` codes those *out-of-range* chars are represented by, you can't do the conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is correct for copying characters from a vector into a string.

Given that the result needs to be UTF-8, if the source is UTF-8, then the program is correct.

If the source is not UTF-8, then you need to somehow convert the encoding. In order to keep the text legible through the conversion, you need to know the encoding of the source data, to know how to perform the conversion.

If the data isn't textual i.e. it is binary, then you can probably use for example Base64 encoding to make it valid UTF-8. You can of course use Base64 with text as well, but the text will not remain readable until it is decoded, and then rendered in the specific encoding that it uses.

Comment: Aha... base64 may have been the answer I was looking for. This is binary data.

Comment: I have used that in the past and forgot about it. Let me investigate.